# Cannot get user id from session in tank auth codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the controller

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
class Response extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('tank_auth');

    }

    function index()
    {
        $status = $this->input->post('status');
        $data['amount'] = $this->input->post('amount');
        $data['orderID'] = $this->input->post('orderID');
        $data['mobileNo'] = $this->input->post('mobileNo');
        $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
            echo "userid is".$this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
    }
 }
```

Im posting some values into the controller after it is done,im trying to get the user id from the session which Im not able to get using tank auth.This is working in other controllers im having
Please help

Comment: Make sure that the session is set.

Comment: The session is set.im using the same in other controller.its working

Comment: Does it gives any error? try this `echo ($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()?$this->tank_auth->get_user_id():"NO SESSION");`

Comment: Im getting NO SESSION as output.What will be the problem

Comment: This means that the session is not set. Seems like You have forgotten to log in.

Comment: Yes I did logged in.Its working fine in other controllers

Comment: Priyanka, I'm in the same sitution, some controllers it works, some not. Did you find a solution?